variational inequality for convex optimization
While learning optimality conditions, I found a proof, that a point $\tilde{x}$ for a convex problem is optimal, iff the variational inequality is satisfied,
$\nabla f(\tilde{x})(x-\tilde{x}) \geq 0, \forall x \in \Omega  $. For the proof it was assumed, that f and $\Omega$ are convex. The proof was very straight forward and understandable. I have read, that theorem also holds, for non-convex, continuous differentiable f but haven't found a proof. One direction is easy enough but following optimality, from the inequality, I get $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\tilde{x}+t(x-\tilde{x}))-f(\tilde{x})}{t} \geq 0, \forall x\in \Omega$. I know, that if I can say, that $ \exists t, f(x)-f(\tilde{x}) \geq 0, \forall x \in B(\tilde{x},t) \cap\Omega $ and that it almost looks like I m there but my problem is, that I feel like I can only make that step, when I choose t dependent on x, which I think is not giving me the same assumption. My question would be, does the variational inequality hold both ways, if $\Omega$ is convex and f continuous differentiable? If so, is there a nice proof?
Edit: Ok I get, that for the case, if the variational inequality is active so $\nabla f(\tilde{x})(x-\tilde{x}) = 0, \forall x \in \Omega  $, $\tilde{x}$ doesn't need to be a minimum, if f is not convex. What if the inequality is strict? So $\nabla f(\tilde{x})(x-\tilde{x}) > 0, \forall x \in \Omega  $?
